# What is (full) conformance?

Tags: standards, standards-compliance

I'm having trouble understanding what is conformance.

Can you please explain to me what does conformance (and full conformance) mean and which idea does it represent? If you could give me an example (code/how it's expressed in a PL) of it too I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I'll give it a shot:

Technologies which are designed to interact with others are subject to *specifications*. Take, for example, the HTTP protocol – there's a [lengthy document](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt) explaining how the communication between two entities has to work if they intend to “speak” HTTP.

If a software is able to interact with another software according to its specification, it *conforms* to the specification. The great thing is, you don't need to know anything about the internals of the other software, just implement the specs, and you're fine.

Sometimes a software is not 100% conformant to the given specification, e.g. when it implements only parts of the specification or intentionally violates the specification.

For example, you could write a relatively simple “HTTP server” with [a single line of shell code](https://razvantudorica.com/08/web-server-in-one-line-of-bash/), but this would be far from a full implementation of the HTTP protocol.

Long story short: *Full conformance* simply means that your implementation fully respects every (mandatory) aspect of a given specification. Not more, not less.

Now, you've tagged your question `standards-compliance` – so, what's the difference between *compliance* and *conformance*? Generally, both terms can be used widely synonymically. However, *conformance* refers to any specification, whereas *compliance* usually refers to a *standard*.

Not every *specification* is a *standard*. For example, I can specify an API for a piece of software or a web service. For example, the Facebook web service APIs are a specification, but not a standard.

A *standard* is a very formal specification of a generic technology, it is being published by some sort of (usually independent) body and is authoritative for the ecosystem it applies to. For example, The HTTP protocol is a standard which has been published by the IETF and is authoritive to all companies, organisations and individuals who develop web servers and web clients such as browsers.